# How to pronounce Las Vegas?

Tags: pronunciation

I have heard Las Vegas being pronounced as Los Vegas and Las Vegas. 
What is the correct way to pronounce Las Vegas ?

Comment: "Lost Wages" is the accurate way.

Comment: Who is pronouncing it? It's the [*cot-caught*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot%E2%80%93caught_merger) merger, which most Las Vegans have, which is confusing you.

Comment: @PeterShor Where is the [ɔ] in *Las Vegas* that could **ever** be subject to the *cot–caught* merger? You may be thinking of *Los Angeles*.

Comment: @tchrist: It's the [ɑ] in *Las Vegas* that's merged with [ɔ] in the *cot-caught* merger. And while people with this merger generally pronounce the merged vowel with [ɑ], it can drift towards [ɒ], which might be heard as *Los Vegas*.

Comment: @PeterShor I see what you mean now. If mergers can’t hear any difference in the [ɔ~ɒ~ɑ] continuum, they can wander around in it willy nilly and never notice it themselves. There **are** (“rustic”?) accents where /ɑ/ can come out with rounding in just the way you mention, like the eye-dialect spellings of *grandmaw* or *paw* try to convey.

Comment: Eeks, I would have thought this'd be a simple question. People from USA and Australia are pronouncing ? What difference does that make ? What's the right way?

Comment: Frankly, most folks in the US could not tell you accurately whether they say "Las" or "Los".  The syllable goes by so fast that it's hard to pin down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way, as you could have checked by looking in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas), is to pronounce it with the vowel of *father*.

There are many people who pronounce all three words *father, pot, fraud* with the same vowel; this is the predominant pronunciation in the Western U.S., including in Las Vegas and Los Angeles. People with this vowel merger pronounce the first word in *Los Angeles* and *Las Vegas* the same way, and they may pronounce *Las Vegas* so that it sounds to some of us like *Loss Vegas*. This might be why you are confused.